# IIS, Users and Memory Estimation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, memory

I have a MVC application that is running on a hosted server. I have an issue that the host is forcing app pool recycles. They say that my RAM is limited to 128mb. While this isn't very much I'm not so sure that my app is causing this - problem is I need to understand how it works!

My app runs at about 25mb with no significant memory leak.

What I don't really understand is how this can get up to 128mb very quickly - seems to be a problem when an admin user is logged in - the user identity is wiped almost immediately.

How does memory usage fluctuate with number of users on the site?

Thanks for any help

Comment: The questions you are asking cannot be answered without knowing what your application does and how it is written. You are asking `How does memory usage fluctuate with number of users on the site?` and the answer is: `that would enormously depend on your code`. For example if you never use ASP.NET Sessions (which is the best practice) it wouldn't really matter because you won't be storing anything in-memory. In this case you won't even care about App Pool recycles because your application would be completely stateless.

Comment: A web server with only 128MiB?  Memory is *cheap*.

Comment: Amy, its shared hosting but they are still being tight... my other host gives 300mb out the box... which should be more than enough

Comment: Darin, While true I'm not sure that that isn't an overly simplistic view. Most websites have 'state' is some form - session, cookie etc. Of course the memory usage fluctuates depending what the users do. This is quite a simple shopping cart website. I am more interested in what is loaded into memory everytime a user hits the site - i don't understand how IIS serves each request?